# Masonry Layout in Scroll View

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am working on an iPhone app which needs a scroll view that populates set of images of different sizes.Currently I am adding the imagViews in a Grid like structure.
But I need to add images in a Masonry layout like structure.**Is there any filling algorithm available in objective C to achieve this**.Please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no algorithms available for iPhone sdk .You can achieve your goal, if you are ready to compromise with the width of the images.Means the images are of variable height and constant width.Then you can align it in a grid structure as you mentioned.

Comment: I am using using images of diffrent sizes, both width and height will be diffrent for each image.

Comment: Hey markz, any helpful hints on how to achieve what you have mentioned.  I am looking for exactly that, fixed widths with variable heights, but I have not been able to come up with a decent algorithm that is efficient and still allows some flexability

Comment: Found https://github.com/chiahsien/UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout and just used the Layout file in the root of the project: UICollectionViewWaterfallLayout